# $array[index] doesn't work for some collections?

Tags: arrays, powershell

Just looking for someone to point me in the right direction please, repeatedly in PowerShell I come across collections that I can't get elements of using [x].

The one I've just hit is in IIS:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll") | Out-Null
$serverManager = New-Object Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager

$site = $servermanager.sites[0]
```

This returns nothing. However, `$servermanager.sites | foreach-object {$site = $_}` correctly loops through each object.

Using gm only returns the members of the object, not the collection, and I've been unable to find anything online to explain this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Actually managed to solve it just after finishing the question using `gettype()` then [looking it up](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.sitecollection(v=vs.90).aspx).

In this particular case you need to use `$servermanager.sites.item(0)` to get the item at index 0.